# libGDX weird object rendering g3d

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, rendering

Im learning with these touturials g3d: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/

I did recreate his code and all worked well.

Now I tried at my own to create the scene of the invaderscene.g3db

My code:

```
public class ScreenLearn3D implements Screen {

private final Game game;
public ScreenLearn3D(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

private PerspectiveCamera camera;
private CameraInputController cameraController;

private Manager manager;

private ModelBatch modelBatch;
private Array<ModelInstance> instances;
private Environment environment;

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    cameraController = new CameraInputController(camera);

    manager = new Manager();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    environment = new Environment();


    camera.position.set(0f, 20f, 20f);
    camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
    camera.near = 0f;
    camera.far = 300f;
    camera.update();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(cameraController);

    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));
}

private void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < manager.model.nodes.size; i++) {
        String id = manager.model.nodes.get(i).id;
        ModelInstance instance = new ModelInstance(manager.model, id);

        instances.add(instance);
    }
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if(manager.update()) {
        setup();
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.fieldOfView = 67f;
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    Gdx.app.log("Dispose", "ScreenLearn3D");

    modelBatch.dispose();
    instances.clear();
}
```

}

```
public final class Manager implements Disposable {
private final AssetManager manager;
private boolean isLoaded;




protected Model model;

public Manager() {
    manager = new AssetManager();
    isLoaded = false;
    load();
}

private void load() {
    manager.load("invaderscene.g3db", Model.class);

}

public boolean update() {
    if (manager.update() && !isLoaded) {
        model = manager.get("invaderscene.g3db");
        // Reference loaded assets

        isLoaded = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    manager.dispose();
    model.dispose();
}
```

}

Now I got a weird showing of the objects...

In front of the camara the objects dissapear
but they apper if I rotate the camera. (when Im far or near allways the same)

1# EDIT: [Link](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4033/uzje3tmx_png.htm)

2# EDIT: Problem solved. camera.near should be over 0.

Comment: A screenshot displaying the problem might help here.

Comment: Try this `camera.near = 0f; camera.far = 300f;` with some more sane values. Something like 0.2f and 100f maybe. Have a look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/129030/why-is-near-clip-plane-necessary.html

Comment: Cant post an image havent got eneugth points for that. I could upload it from somwere else and post the link when im at home.